# Deploying a smart contract from EVM Bytecode via rpc calls

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, parity

I am currently trying to deploy a smart contract with bytecode in a private Ethereum chain, using the "dev" chain of the parity client. For this, I compiled the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract MyContract {
    uint i = (10 + 2) * 2;
}
```

with solidity:

```
solc --bin test.sol 

======= test.sol:MyContract =======
Binary: 
    608060405260186000553480156014576     
    00080fd5b5060358060226000396000f3006080604052600080fd00a165627a7a72305820d0cc3f28b74510b6f3f34e1a1e1303c584b355320f387a3e30022117e3554e220029
```

I then used the following rpc call to create the transaction:

```
Request: {"method": "personal_sendTransaction", "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": [{"from": "0x0053b6a9527c2ba72cf44486dd12d9930ce25bae", "data": "0x60806040526018600055348015601457600080fd5b5060358060226000396000f3006080604052600080fd00a165627a7a72305820d0cc3f28b74510b6f3f34e1a1e1303c584b355320f387a3e30022117e3554e220029"}, "test"]}.
```

where `0x0053b6a9527c2ba72cf44486dd12d9930ce25bae` is an account on the private Chain which has ether and the passphrase `test`.

This is the answer I get:

```
Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0xf547c28a3f51c05832fadd4b807f5bb769196970d08e446b2644a2ea94359572","id":1}.
```

But the byte string given in `result` is not a valid address. How do I get the address of the contract I created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you got is the "transaction hash" ( tx ), which you can then pass to a "eth_getTransactionReceipt" call in order to get the actual contract address.

See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionreceipt

```
// Example Call / Request 

curl -X POST --data'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238"],"id":1}'

// Result
{
    "id":1,
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "result": {
         transactionHash: '0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238',
         transactionIndex:  '0x1', // 1
         blockNumber: '0xb', // 11
         blockHash: '0xc6ef2fc5426d6ad6fd9e2a26abeab0aa2411b7ab17f30a99d3cb96aed1d1055b',
         cumulativeGasUsed: '0x33bc', // 13244
         gasUsed: '0x4dc', // 1244
         contractAddress: '0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155', // or null, if none was created
         logs: [{
             // logs as returned by getFilterLogs, etc.
         }, ...],
         logsBloom: "0x00...0", // 256 byte bloom filter
         status: '0x1'
    }
}
```